# How to convert a 2D video to 3D/180°?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, 3d, 2d

I am trying to create a 3D side by side video from a 2D video. Apparently, there are some paid software under Windows that are able to do this and I would like to do the same thing under Linux with free software.

Actually, I can almost do it with ffmpeg via the following command:

`ffmpeg -i video-2D.mkv -i video-2D.mkv -filter_complex "hstack,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -s 3200:1440 -c:a copy video-3D.mp4`

But I think that it would be necessary to create an offset of an eye for the effect of depth, can you or do you have an idea please to make better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but someone else might need this information.

I recently created a shell script port based on a windows cmd script that I read from this article/post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusQuest/comments/sq5lua/simple_script_for_2d_to_3d_video_conversion/

The illusion of depth and motion employed in the script is very interesting as it is based on the Pulfrich effect. To quote verbatim from the article:

> "The Pulfrich effect is a psychophysical percept wherein lateral
> motion of an object in the field of view is interpreted by the visual
> cortex as having a depth component, due to a relative difference in
> signal timings between the two eyes."

This could be done by delaying the right side video by 1 over the original frame rate of the input video. The script does this by employing a ***setpts*** filter:

```
right_delay=$(bc -l <<< "1/($fps)")

ffmpeg -i "$inp" -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=$new_width:$new_height,crop=$width:$new_height:$crop_width:0[left];
[0:v]scale=$new_width:$new_height,crop=$width:$new_height:0:0,
setpts=(PTS-$right_delay/TB)[right];
[left][right]hstack" \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 28 "$outp"
```

From my experience converting videos from 2D to 3D SBS using this technique, I can say that the effect mentioned above sometimes works nicely but also sometimes produces a jarring effect in the SBS video.

You can certainly see what I am talking about if you try the script yourself.

The original script from the article is located here:
https://github.com/threedguru/threedguru/blob/main/cv3DSBS.cmd

The shell script version (tested only on MacOSX but will probably work on Linux) is located here:
https://gist.github.com/javelin/0615bc6fbd30fa220a3681bbb6409e5d